# How does Apache resolves the requested virtual host?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I am running several virtual hosts on a VPS running Apache 2.4.

I registered a domain at my VPS provider OVH: 55eastmonroe.software.

I want the subdomain www.55eastmonroe.software to point to the same site, so beside the A record (55eastmonroe.software), I created a CNAME record: www.55eastmonroe.software

But when I navigate to www.55eastmonroe.software, the server returns the default Apache page (defined in the 000-default.conf file).

Here is my 002-wp_em.conf file

[image: Virtual Host configuration]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy them and apply code-formatting instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 55eastmonroe.software
    ServerAlias www.55eastmonroe.software
    DocumentRoot /var/www/em_home
</VirtualHost>
```

See the [docs about name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/name-based.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the `VirtualHost` section, try adding a `ServerAlias www.55eastmonroe.software` entry, or even `ServerAlias *.55eastmonroe.software`.